# Getting undefined data with RTK query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I use RTK query to get properties with a filter is applied.

```
export const propertiesSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
        getCityFilter: builder.query({
            query: (city) => '/api/properties/filter?city=${city}',
        }),
})
export const {useLazyGetCityFilterQuery} = propertiesSlice;
```

The above code makes api call and returns list of properties for the city.

Component:

```
const [getPropertiesbyCity, { data: filteredProperty }] = useLazyGetCityFilterQuery();
    const handleCityFilter = async (city) => {
        naviagte('?city=${city}')
        try {
            await getPropertiesbyCity(city);
            console.log("filteredProperty ----", filteredProperty);
            dispatch(setProperties(filteredProperty));
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching filtered properties:", error);
        }
    }
```

Here, the filertedProperty is undefined. While cross checking, api does return data.
Network call :

> [ {
> "_id": "64dcbfb2a937268110300768",
> "title": "New test",
> "propertyType": "house",
> "rent": 20000,
> "buildUpArea": 2000,
> "carpetArea": 1800,
> "bedrooms": 2,
> "bathrooms": 2,
> "parking": false,
> "listedBy": "64dc5d5d547a952168b55d4c",
> "propertyOn": "",
> "bachelorsAllowed": true,
> "securityDeposit": 100000,
> "petAllowed": false,
> "nonVegetarian": true,
> "propertyDescription": "Test desc",
> "city": "Bangalore",
> "state": "kerala",
> "country": "india",
> "location": "JP nagar",
> "listedOn": "2023-08-16T12:23:14.097Z",
> "createdAt": "2023-08-16T12:23:14.098Z",
> "updatedAt": "2023-08-16T12:23:14.098Z",
> "__v": 0 } ]

But the returned data is not getting seen in the callback of the useLazyGetCityFilterQuery.
The same works, when I not use useLazy instead a normal useGetCityFilterQuery. But I don't need the api to call unless a button is clicked or cityParam is in the url. So, using useLazyGetCityFilterQuery does allow me to do so.

I'm trying to get the data in useLazyGetCityFilterQuery return.